# Im trying to execute "./byfn.sh" up to test hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When i run ./byfn.sh up send me this error.

LOCAL_VERSION=1.4.3
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=2.3.3

```
=================== WARNING ===================
  Local fabric binaries and docker images are
  out of  sync. This may cause problems.
===============================================
```

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "scripts/script.sh": stat scripts/script.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
ERROR !!!! Test failed.

I see the LOCAL_VERSION is different to DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION. How could i change that? Well... I think thats the problem roght?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

your bin folder in fabric-samples has binaries of version  1.4.3 where as docker images version is 2.2.3.
`docker images`  to list the images in the system.
The latest fabric-samples doesn't have the BYFN it now works around test-network with 2 organizations and 1 peer each. download the latest fabric-samples and binaries with the curl command `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s` it will download the latest samples and binaries and the docker images if you need of specific version like 2.2.3 then
`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 2.2.3 1.5.2`
you can find more details here in this link for getting latest samples and binaries  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/install.html#install-samples-binaries-and-docker-images